# Convert Object Serialized with Pickle to String in Python

Tags: python, character-encoding, pickle

I am attempting to convert the output of `pickle.dumps` into a string, though I am met with an error message relating to string encoding.

Code with Error:

```py
import pickle

class TestClass:
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number

t1 = TestClass(14)
s1 = pickle.dumps(t1)
str_version = s1.decode('utf-8', 'backslashreplace')
print(pickle.loads(str_version.encode('utf-8', 'backslashreplace')))
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ketha\Downloads\python_testing.py", line 11, in <module>
    print(pickle.loads(str_version.encode('utf-8', 'backslashreplace')))
_pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '\x5c'.
```

I think this is because when I convert it to a string, it converts `\x5c` (for example) to `\\x5c` and doesn't undo this during decoding. How could I undo this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got some code working. Code:

```py
import pickle
import sys

class TestClass:
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number

t1 = TestClass(14)
s1 = pickle.dumps(t1)
str_version = s1.decode('unicode_escape')
decoded = pickle.loads(str_version.encode('utf-8', 'unicode_escape').replace(b'\xc2', b''))
print(decoded.number)
```